# WP_Query causing Wordpress dashboard to disappear

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

For some reason after I use a while loop inside an if statement after creating a new WP query object, my dashboard disappears.

```
<?php 

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'info'
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>
<?php if( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
    <section class="info">
        <p class="quote"><?php the_field('quote'); ?></p>
        <div class="text">
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
        </div>
    </section>  
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset(); ?>
```

Removing the if statement and while loop causes the dashboard to reappear again. This appears to be the correct formatting, I cannot find another case where someone had this same problem.

Comment: I wonder that `$query` is reserved, what if you change it to something else?

Comment: I don't think it is. I just tried a different variable name, and it still won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about if you correct the last bit `wp_reset();` to `wp_reset_postdata();`?

Answer (score 0):

Try `get_posts()` function instead of `new WP_Query( );` .

Something like that :

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'info'
);
$myposts = get_posts($args);
foreach ($myposts as $post) :
    setup_postdata($post);
    ?>
    <section class="info">
        <p class="quote"><?php the_field('quote'); ?></p>
        <div class="text">
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
        </div>
    </section>  
<?php endforeach;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Hope it helps you.